# Raspbian Jessie boot issue after dd image install from Arch partition

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, filesystem

I originally used NOOBS to create this card and it had Wheezie + Arch Linux.  I had some issues with the wheezie installation so I:

-downloaded and unziped the Jessie image onto my Arch partition,

-mounted the image partitions read only onto loop devices,

-dd from loop0 to the Wheezy boot partition ensuring the block count matched the image's block count,

-dd from loop1 to the Wheezy partition also paying attention to the block count,

-emptied the boot folder from the newly Jessified partition,

-mounted the Jessie partition and the boot partition inside it,

-made sure the cmdline.txt file referenced the Jessie partition instead of the default mmcblk0p2,

Then rebooted.

I selected Raspbian and it began to boot, but when it got to the fsck portion of boot it went nuts.  It repeats messages like this:

```
[ 2629.015643] systemd-fsck[251]: /os/<unintelligible ASCII characters here>
Bad short file name (<more ASCII garbage>
Auto-renaming it.
Renamed to FSCK0003.863
```

It started at FSCK0000.001, so yeah, it has hit some 4000 "files" and keeps going.  Also, the bad file names seem to have a similar effect to catting binaries to stdout, scrambling garbage characters into the output for a page or two.
I interrupted it by unplugging it and rebooting to Arch.

I can still mount the partitions and even chroot into it (adjusting $PATH to compensate for the /usr/bin /bin difference between the distros).  The Jessie file system seems fine and fsck's fine.  The lost+found is empty.

What could be wrong and what step did I miss at what time to cause this?

edit:  If it sounds like I did everything right but something broke that shouldn't have, that's a valid answer, too.  I'll do it again if it *should* just work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Gahh!  I figured it out.  Stupid mistake:  I forgot to edit the Raspbian root partition /etc/fstab to specify the partitions.  All good now.  I have no idea whether I destroyed any partition 1 or partition 2 stuff though...